# about receiving timing of iOS LocalNotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I get a problem about the UILocalNotification

There are 2 conditions now:

1) When APP is in background, and receive a local notification, then touch the notification

```
 APP run:
 applicationWillEnterForeground
 didReceiveLocalNotification
 applicationDidBecomeActive
```

2) When APP is in progress of transfering from background to forground,and at this moment(maybe 0.1 sec),local notification comes

```
 APP run:
 applicationWillEnterForeground
 didReceiveLocalNotification
 applicationDidBecomeActive
```

Question:

Since the above flow of two conditions seems to be completely the same.
How could I judge current condition is 1) or 2) ?
According to iOS API document, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() should be 
run in condition of 1) when APP is in background.And in that function the 
APP starting mode can be known by parameter. But the actual result I've 
tryed is that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() will be run only if APP is 
finished.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how are you testing this? did you check `applicationState` ?

Comment: In didReceiveLocalNotification I did check applicationState and value is inactive state on both conditions.